# can javascript be inline with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to import a library to my project, the library should is a javascript file, which need to be inlined to html.

for example:

library code：

```
(function(){
   var a = 0;
})();
```

I need to make this code inline in html.

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      (function(){
         var a = 0;
      })();
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

can I implement this with webpack?
I find [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader), but it run the script, not make it inline.

Comment: Can I ask the specific reason why you want to add it to html file rather than js bundle created by webpack.?

Comment: @sandeep  it is a responsive page solution which set the font-size of html directive according to the mobile device's size. it need to be executed before the page is rendered.

Comment: That should be done with CSS `@media`, not with JS. But if there is JS you want to run before the `<body>` is parsed, add the `<script>` tag to the `<head>` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At last, we solve this problem by combining webpack and gulp. (with two plugins: gulp-html-replace and gulp-inline-source.)

html:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <!-- build:js -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

gulpfile:

```
  gulp.task('replace-and-inline', function () {
      return gulp.src('./dist/index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
          'js': {
            src: [your libs which you want to be inline],
            tpl: '<script src="%s" inline></script>'
          }
        }))
        .pipe(inlinesource())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
    });
```

In package.json, define a task, which will compile the project using webpack and then inject the js file as inline.

```
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --hide-modules --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js;gulp replace-and-inline"
```

When you want to release your project, just run `npm run build`

---

update on July.20 2018

we have made a webpack plugin to solve this issue.

https://github.com/QuellingBlade/html-webpack-inline-plugin

Comment: Hi, does your plugin still works? I tried but not working

Comment: Hello ,I use your plugin, but it dont work in webpack5 and html-webpack-plugin 5.5.

Answer (score 24):

I've started working on a [plugin](https://github.com/dustinjackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin) for [html webpack](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) to support this.  You specify regex to match files that you want to embed inline.

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' // embed all javascript and css inline
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
]
```

Answer (score 8):

I did it without gulp, with the help of [inline-source](https://github.com/popeindustries/inline-source):

1. Install inline-source-cli: `npm install inline-source-cli`
2. Add an `inline` attribute to the script tag in your html file: `<script inline src="path/to/index.js"></script>`
3. Run `inline-source --root ./dist dist/path/to/index-pre.html > dist/path/to/index.html`

Comment: a bit cleaner to stick to just webpack though

Answer (score 0):

for webpack 4, I tried the following 3 plugins but no luck

1. html-webpack-inline-plugin
2. html-webpack-inline-source-plugin
3. script-ext-html-webpack-plugin

then I found this [react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin.js) so borrow it and modify to fit my needs:

```
// use it like this
            ...
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin(...),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin(...),
            new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/[.]js$/, /[.]css$/]),
            ...

// modify InlineChunkHtmlPlugin to inline both script and style
class InlineChunkHtmlPlugin {
    constructor(htmlWebpackPlugin, tests) {
        this.htmlWebpackPlugin = htmlWebpackPlugin;
        this.tests = tests;
    }

    isScript(tag) {
        return tag.tagName === 'script' && tag.attributes && tag.attributes.src;
    }

    isCss(tag) {
        return tag.tagName === 'link' && tag.attributes && tag.attributes.href && tag.attributes.rel === "stylesheet";
    }

    getInlinedTag(publicPath, assets, tag) {
        //debugger;
        const isScript = this.isScript(tag);
        const isCss = this.isCss(tag);
        if (!isScript && !isCss) {
            return tag;
        }

        const href = isScript ? tag.attributes.src : tag.attributes.href;

        const scriptName = publicPath
            ? href.replace(publicPath, '')
            : href;
        if (!this.tests.some(test => scriptName.match(test))) {
            return tag;
        }
        const asset = assets[scriptName];
        if (asset == null) {
            return tag;
        }
        return { tagName: isScript ? 'script' : 'style', innerHTML: asset.source(), closeTag: true };
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        let publicPath = compiler.options.output.publicPath || '';
        if (publicPath && !publicPath.endsWith('/')) {
            publicPath += '/';
        }

        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('InlineChunkHtmlPlugin', compilation => {
            const tagFunction = tag =>
                this.getInlinedTag(publicPath, compilation.assets, tag);

            const hooks = this.htmlWebpackPlugin.getHooks(compilation);
            hooks.alterAssetTagGroups.tap('InlineChunkHtmlPlugin', assets => {
                assets.headTags = assets.headTags.map(tagFunction);
                assets.bodyTags = assets.bodyTags.map(tagFunction);
            });

            // Still emit the runtime chunk for users who do not use our generated
            // index.html file.
            // hooks.afterEmit.tap('InlineChunkHtmlPlugin', () => {
            //   Object.keys(compilation.assets).forEach(assetName => {
            //     if (this.tests.some(test => assetName.match(test))) {
            //       delete compilation.assets[assetName];
            //     }
            //   });
            // });
        });
    }
}
```